# Reference implementation / .lib for full url encoding

Tags: java, html, http, parsing, browser

I'm writing a Java application which parses links from html & uses them to request their content. The area of url encoding when we have no idea of the "intent" of the url author is very thorny. For example when to use %20 or + is a complex issue: ([%20 vs +](http://www.lunatech-research.com/archives/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)), a browser would perform this encoding for a url containing an un-encoded space.

There are many other situations in which a browser would change the content of a parsed url before requesting a page, for example:

```
http://www.Example.com/&#254;
```

... when parsed & requested by a browser becomes ...

```
http://www.Example.com/%C3%BE
```

.. and...

```
http://www.Example.com/&amp;
```

... when parsed & requested by a browser becomes ...

```
http://www.Example.com/&
```

So my question is, instead of re-inventing the wheel again is there perhaps a Java library I haven't found to do this job? Failing that can anyone point me towards a reference implementation in a common browsers source? or perhaps pseudo code? Failing that, any recommendations on approach welcome!

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Your real problem here is how you handle illegal URLs. Your first example, for instance, is not a legal URL, because, after resolving the HTML escape, it contains a þ, which is not a character permitted anywhere in a URL. It can be present in the fields that make up a URL, but not in a composed, encoded URL. So, you have to take a leap of faith and re-encode bits of a URL, which as your excellent link says, is a terrible thing to do.

Comment: @Tom - Agreed. I've seen bug reports for Chrome which end up saying they'll change the area that handles this to work more like ie. I think it's something crying out for a w3c standard. Unfortunately it would appear MS created a de-facto standard with IE that others are now following :(.

Comment: Actually - probably not something for a new standard. As you point out, the problems are sometimes arising from people not following the published standard, and the browser having to do a best guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) can certainly pick URLs out of HTML and resolve them (and much more).

I don't know whether it handles your corner cases, though. I would imagine it will handle the second, since that is a normal, if slightly funny-looking, use of HTML and a URL. I don't know what it will do with the second, in which an invalid URL is encoded in HTML.

I also know that if you find that HTMLUnit does something differently to how real browsers do it, write a JUnit test case to prove it, and file a bug report, then its maintainers will happily fix it with great alacrity.

Comment: Tom - I think you may be onto a winner there. Their UrlUtilities class includes an encodeUrl method which looks like exactly what I want. I'll play with that and accept your answer assuming first impressions pan out :)

http://htmlunit.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/htmlunit/trunk/htmlunit/src/main/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/util/UrlUtils.java?revision=6523&view=markup

Comment: Yep - all good; url's need a pre-process with StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml from apache commons (I imagine HtmlUnit does that elsewhere in their pasrsing), then its perfect. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

How about using java.net.URLEncoder.encode() & java.net.URLDecoder.decode().

Comment: Unfortunately they don't work for the scenario for a couple of reasons: 1) They don't do any encoding of things like html entities. 2) They attempt to encode the whole url (including before the ? and after the #), when they're used on a full url they even try encoding the / characters.

Comment: Ok.  Are the scenarios you list above the input and the expected output?

Comment: Yes. I produced those with chrome & checked against IE.

Comment: URLEncoder, despite the name, doesn't encode URLs. It handles, as the documentation says, "converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format". It's terribly named.

Comment: "It's terribly named", agreed. The naming of the commons version (URLCodec) is a little better.